# Jstree remembering the selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am loading the jstree using li and ul tags . Now I want to remember the selections which users has made , and want to store it in some json to make use of it later.

For example jstree is loaded with some values after that , I want to reload the same tree with the values which are not selected then tree becomes shorter and will show only those values which are not selected , then again user switches back to the full view by clicking some button , now here I want to assure that the values selected by user when in shorter view are also present in full view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way of remembering the selections is something like , go on and store the id's of your

nodes if you want to use in future and just hide the id's which you want to hide using style , display:none.

I hope this helps.